# How to execute another MySqlDataReader for each read ID?

Tags: c#, mysqldatareader

I'm trying to get from my database some `data`, each of that `data` may have some `attributes`, so my logic was while i'm getting all `data` so while the `MySqlDataReader` is executed i was going to execute the query for each `id` of data i got to get it's `attributes`.

But i run in to error: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection' so my guess is that i can't run at the same time the `MySqlDataReader` so at this point, which would be the best approach to get `attributes` for each `data`?

Should i just cycle on each `Plu` element after i've added them to the list or is there a better solution?

Here is the function where i get the `data` (Plu object)

```
        public IEnumerable<Plu> GetPlu(string piva, int menu)
        {
            string connectionString = $"CONSTR";
            using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            var sql = @"QUERY";

            using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@menu", menu);
            cmd.Prepare();

            using MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Plu> plu = new List<Plu>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                plu.Add(new Plu(
                    (int)reader["ID_PLUREP"],
                    (string)reader["CODICE_PRP"],
                    (string)reader["ESTESA_DES"],
                    (string)reader["DESCR_DES"], (float)reader["PRE_PRP"],
                    reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("IMG_IMG")) ? null : (string)reader["IMG_IMG"],
                    Attributi(connection, (int)reader["ID_PLUREP"])
                    ));
            }

            return plu; 
        }
```

And here is function Attributi which return the IEnumerable of `attributes` for each `Plu`

```
        public IEnumerable<Plu.Attributi> Attributi(MySqlConnection connection, int idplu)
        {
            var sql = @"QUERY";

            using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idplu", idplu);
            cmd.Prepare();

            List<Plu.Attributi> attributi = new List<Plu.Attributi>();

            using MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                attributi.Add(new Plu.Attributi(
                        reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("BCKCOL_ATT")) ? null : (string)reader["BCKCOL_ATT"],
                        reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FORCOL_ATT")) ? null : (string)reader["FORCOL_ATT"],
                        reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("DESCR_ATT")) ? null : (string)reader["DESCR_ATT"]
                        ));
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an open connection with a reader already executing. Open a new connection in Attributi.

```cs
public IEnumerable<Plu.Attributi> Attributi(int idplu)
{
    var sql = @"QUERY";

    using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        connection.Open();
        using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idplu", idplu);
            cmd.Prepare();

            List<Plu.Attributi> attributi = new List<Plu.Attributi>();

            using MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    attributi.Add(new Plu.Attributi(
                        reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("BCKCOL_ATT")) ? null : (string)reader["BCKCOL_ATT"],
                        reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FORCOL_ATT")) ? null : (string)reader["FORCOL_ATT"],
                        reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("DESCR_ATT")) ? null : (string)reader["DESCR_ATT"]
                        ));
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

<s>BTW, your usage of `using` is totally off. You need a block after the using statement where you deal with everything regarding the `IDisposable` object.</s>

**EDIT:** Apparently that's a new .NET Core 3.1 feature.

Comment: i've read that in .NET Core 3.1 `using` doesn't need anymore of the block statement, quotes from Microsoft docs:  `Beginning with C# 8.0, you can use the following alternative syntax for the using statement that doesn't require braces`

Comment: @Igor [Yep, you're right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations), and I'm glad this has come to C#.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me on the `using` pattern. I wasn't aware of that. I'll keep using the old syntax though. I'm not on .NET Core, and I actually think it's helpful that the code is in an indented block. IT makes it very clear where the disposing is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

For the more general case, my experience with `MySQL` has lead me to always "free" my reader with:

```
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(reader);
```

Then working from the `DataTable` rather than the `MySqlDataReader`, you can then reuse the connection as you prefer.